# Problem with hasura cli metadata apply && hasura migrate apply

Tags: hasura

I've tried to execute a command of hasura cli

```
hasura metadata apply && hasura migrate apply --database-name default && hasura metadata reload
```

Doing so, I get this error:

> FATA[0000] cannot read config: invalid config version.

My version of hasura config.yml is 3, and the server: v2.0.0-alpha.4.

Comment: share the config file

Comment: Please share the config

Comment: Is other commands like create migration, create metadata..etc are working?